# Parsing CSV causing out of memory in php

Tags: php

I am using adwords reporting api to get all ad's and keyword's info for all the adwords account. Currently account count is 1363. Reporting api generates a CSV which I am parsing it to Array below is the function. After parsing a good 1180 account it gives an error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) .

I have set memory to 512MB (which I believe is a lot).

The error comes on this line

```
$line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
```

private function convertCSVtoArray($csvFile){

```
    try {
        $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
            $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }
        fclose($file_handle);
        return $line_of_text;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        log_message('Exception in convertCSVtoArray()', $e);
        throw new Exception('Exception in convertCSVtoArray => '.$e);
    }
}
```

The above function is called from a method

```
$data = $this->convertCSVtoArray($filePath);
```

I believe, there is a memory leak somewhere in the given code which is eating all the memory.

Please suggest if there is any solution.

Comment: That is rather interesting. Is this the only file you're reading? Based on record count (1360) and `fgetcsv` length specified (1024): that only consumes about 2-4MB in my tests. Have you used `memory_get_usage` before running `convertCSVtoArray` to make sure the memory usage isn't already high before the call? (As a likely unrelated aside: you should add a check to make sure you've actually gotten a read handle before entering that loop. If `fopen` returns false, you'll get an infinite loop that continues until you hit the memory limit as `feof` will never return true.)

Answer (score 0):

To change the memory limit for one specific script, include a line such as this at the top of the script:

ini_set("memory_limit","12M");

You can also make this a permanent change for all PHP scripts running on the server by adding a line such as this to the server’s php.ini file:

memory_limit = 12M